# IE9 - Not able to disable ESC key to stop closing lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

I have used below code - Its not working on IE9 but works fine on Firefox and Chrome

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if (document.addEventListener) {   // all browsers except IE before version 9
        document.addEventListener ("keydown", win_onkeydown_handler, false);
    } 
    else {
        if (document.attachEvent) {    // IE before version 9
            document.attachEvent ('onkeydown', win_onkeydown_handler);
        }
    }

    function win_onkeydown_handler(e, keyEventArgs) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            return false;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `event.returnValue` for older IEs, and prevent the default action in IE>8 :

```
function win_onkeydown_handler(e, keyEventArgs) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        e.returnValue = false;
        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```